# "Syntax error" on button click in iframe (SQL Report)

Tags: html, iframe, reporting-services, internet-explorer-11, reporting-services-2016

In an application I am showing a SQL report inside an `iframe`. Inside the report there are some buttons for expanding a tree view. When I open the URL directly in browser (Internet Explorer 11), I can use these buttons without any problem. When clicking on the buttons through the `iframe`, I get the following error:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

I don't know how to handle this error as there is no error when opening the report directly...

It's probably not necessary but here is the code of the `iframe`:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="MyUrl/MyReport?SomeParameters"></iframe>
```

I've tried adding `rs:Embed=true` to the URL but that didn't change anything.

It could have been a problem with the browser but then the report should not load correctly when opening it directly or am I wrong? How can I show the report inside the `iframe` as it is?

Comment: What if open report inside iframe in Chrome? Will it be failing with some errors?

Comment: Omg you gave me a hint to the right direction... while trying to download Chrome on the server, I found out that I didn't activate JavaScript... -_-

Comment: Haha:) Glad that I helped you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem, thanks to @grafgenerator. He suggested using Chrome. I couldn't download it on the server because of some settings. When I wanted to change the settings, I noticed that JavaScript wasn't activated. After activating it, the errors disappeared.